# How can cef support H.264 and flash?

Tags: flash, h.264, chromium-embedded

I'm now developing an app with cef3 for Windows. I know that chromium has just dropped supprort for H.264. But is there another way that I can make my application play mp4 and flash video?

Comment: Did you find anything?

Answer (score 3):

You need to reconfigure CEF build with at least

*GYP_DEFINES="proprietary_codecs=1 ffmpeg_branding=Chrome"*

The full GYP_DEFINES is

*GYP_DEFINES="branding=Chromium buildtype=Official proprietary_codecs=1 ffmpeg_branding=Chrome", GYP_GENERATORS="ninja,msvs-ninja", GYP_MSVS_VERSION="2013"*

More info:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/delphichromiumembedded/8jisGiqxD-Y
https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=371

You will need license for codecs. Chromium/CEF do not include them for licensing reasons.

Answer (score 1):

the options to enable `proprietary codecs` (i.e. H.264) have been moved.

you can read my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45404590/7588861) with all the details.