# How to enable H264 support in CEF3 latest version ?

Tags: h.264, chromium-embedded

I have known that cef3's older version like 2623 can enable H264 support through modify chromium\src\cef\cef.gypi file.
But in recent versions like 3071 or 3029, cef3 has removed cef.gypi file.
I have googled this,  but what I found is still through modify the cef.gypi file. 
Since this methold  is only valid for older versions. Is there another way that I can make newer version enable H264  support ?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Indeed the compile option to support `proprietary codecs` was moved.

the magic now happens here:

```
set GN_DEFINES=is_official_build=true proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
```

there is 2 batch files that you should update/create (as found [here](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13515&start=40#p35221)):

*c:\code\chromium_git\update.bat:*

```
set CEF_USE_GN=1
set GN_DEFINES=is_official_build=true proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
set GN_ARGUMENTS=--ide=vs2015 --sln=cef --filters=//cef/*
python ..\automate\automate-git.py --download-dir=C:\code\chromium_git --depot-tools-dir=C:\code\depot_tools --no-distrib --no-build
```

*c:\code\chromium_git\chromium\src\cef\create.bat:*

```
set CEF_USE_GN=1
set GN_DEFINES=is_win_fastlink=true proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
set GN_ARGUMENTS=--ide=vs2015 --sln=cef --filters=//cef/*
call cef_create_projects.bat
```

There is 2 wiki articles that explain how to build CEF/Chromium:

1. https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart.md
2. and `BranchesAndBuilding` in the same wiki

---

**Update:**
Here are more links with infos on Chromium build flags:

https://www.chromium.org/developers/gn-build-configuration
https://www.chromium.org/audio-video
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkcr/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

```
... GYP/GN flags which can alter behaviour of Chromium's HTML5 audio/video implementation.

ffmpeg_branding
  Overrides which version of FFmpeg to use
  Default: $(branding)
  Values:
    Chrome - includes additional proprietary codecs (MP3, etc..) for use with Google Chrome
    Chromium - builds default set of codecs

proprietary_codecs
  Alters the list of codecs Chromium claims to support, which affects <source> and canPlayType() behaviour
  Default: 0(gyp)/false(gn)
  Values:
    0/false - <source> and canPlayType() assume the default set of codecs
    1/true - <source> and canPlayType() assume they support additional proprietary codecs
```

Comment: Quick note, disable your anti-virus when building. Not only will it speed it up significantly, some AV trigger during the build process and scuppering hours of your time.