# Build CEF with proprietary codecs support in OSX Sierra

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, chromium-embedded

I am trying to enable mp3 support in `CEF 3.3239.1697.g4c795f5` in OSX Sierra. I typed the following sequence of commands.

```
set CEF_USE_GN=1 
set GN_DEFINES=is_official_build=true proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
python /Users/myusername/Projects/cef_src/automate-git.py
--download-dir=/Users/myusername/Projects/cef_src/v1 --no-release-build --x64-build
```

The binary (`cefclient`) was built but if I open `html5test.com`, it says mp3 is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you actually didn't set any flags, because `set` is not the correct command to do that (`set` is for Windows batch, not Linux/OSX). I'm not quite sure about OSX, but I believe you need to do something like this:

```
export CEF_USE_GN=1
export GN_DEFINES="is_official_build=true proprietary_codecs=1 ffmpeg_branding=Chrome"
```

Not sure you need the quotes there. Please also see my response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45404590/7588861).

Make sure to set the magic flags in both scripts: *update.bat* ***and*** *create.bat*.

Some info on MP3 and OSX [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=746579). Quote: `We have approval from legal to go ahead and move mp3 into non-proprietary codecs list; lets go ahead and do this for the M62 ffmpeg roll.`