# CEF MP4 support

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded

I have rebuilt cef from source with the **proprietary_codecs** option set to **true**, but I still cannot play mp4 videos for some reason. Is there a specific switch that I need to enable ? This is what I used to create the version of cef with support for proprietary codecs

```
set CEF_USE_GN=1
set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN = 0
set GN_DEFINES=is_official_build=true proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome enable_precompiled_headers = false
set GN_ARGUMENTS=--ide=vs2015 --sln=cef --filters=//cef/*
python d:\code\automate\automate-git.py --download-dir=D:\code\chromium_git --depot-tools-dir=D:\code\depot_tools --no-distrib --no-build --branch=3239
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable H264 support in CEF3 latest version ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845493/how-to-enable-h264-support-in-cef3-latest-version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 main steps in the build, one that calls automate-git.py and the second one that creates the cef projects (create.bat). I had the proper GN_DEFINES set in the first one but not the second one. I added the GN_DEFINES (is_official_build=true proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome ) to the second one and it picked up a lot more files during the build. Now I can play mp4 files

Comment: as commented in your own question, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845493/how-to-enable-h264-support-in-cef3-latest-version and answered there with all details

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart.md)

Add this to `update.bat`:

```
set CEF_USE_GN=1
set GN_DEFINES=ffmpeg_branding=Chrome proprietary_codecs=true is_official_build=true use_thin_lto=false chrome_pgo_phase=false
set GN_ARGUMENTS=--ide=vs2022 --sln=cef --filters=//cef/*
python3 ..\automate\automate-git.py --download-dir=c:\code\chromium_git --depot-tools-dir=c:\code\depot_tools --no-distrib --no-build --branch=5938
```

This will take some time to complete.

Add this to `create.bat`:

```
set CEF_USE_GN=1
set GN_DEFINES=ffmpeg_branding=Chrome proprietary_codecs=true is_official_build=true use_thin_lto=false chrome_pgo_phase=false
set GN_ARGUMENTS=--ide=vs2022 --sln=cef --filters=//cef/*
call cef_create_projects.bat
```

After this, run that ninja build command mentioned in documentation.

This is how I built cef 117 version with proprietary_codecs, and I was able to play mp4 videos.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).