# JCEF Build with H.264 Codec

Tags: java, frameworks, chromium-embedded

for my project I want to integrate the java chromium embedded framework. I was able to build it by myself with this tutorial:https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding

In this builded version the browser is not capable of showing mp4 files / h.264 codecs.
How is it possible to activate mp4 codec?

I have read this answer: [How to enable H264 support in CEF3 latest version ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845493/how-to-enable-h264-support-in-cef3-latest-version)

But i cannot find the update.bat. Where is it located?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have built JNI for CEF. You have to build CEF in accordance to the manual https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart and optional https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding. They use update.bat or update.sh.

If you build libcef successfully, you can replace the old libcef.